# Issue displaying a letter made of asterisks

Tags: java, letters

I would like to display the letter `A` made of asterisks. First the program will ask for the size of the letter and depending on the given size it will scale the letter to be that size.

This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. As you can see it only prints one line. Any help would be great.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public  class Problem7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input, size, i;

        System.out.print("Enter a size: ");
        input = kbd.nextInt();

        while (input <= 1) {
            System.out.print("Enter a size: ");
            input = kbd.nextInt();
        }
        for (int col = 0; col < input; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < input; row++) {
                if (col == 1 || col == input || row == col)
                    System.out.print("*");
                else
                    System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Enter a size: 5
*    *****  *     *     *
```

Comment: How do you think your code should work and why do you think so?

Comment: When you need it to print in the next line, use `System.out.println()` or add a `\n` to the string you are printing, or use `%n` in `System.out.printf()`.

Comment: Looks like you need to switch the order of your for loops and after you get done with row you need to have system.out.println().

Comment: so after my first for loop i should have the system.out .print ("*") ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a new line just use:

```
System.out.print("\n");
```

Comment: That would be two newlines.

Comment: `ln` suffix indicates that this method will add line separator automatically. Either use `print("\n")` or `println()`.

Comment: tried putting the ln in println but it just prints in one column now